# Unexpected working of Negated Shorthand Character Classes

Tags: regex, regex-negation

The Regular expression

```
/[\D\S]/
```

should match characters Which is not a digit or not whitespace

But When I test this expression in regexpal

It starts matching any character that's digit, whitespace

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: You wrote the answer yourself: *Every* character is "not a digit" or "not a whitespace".

Comment: but i missed the OR thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\D` = all characters except digits,
`\S` = all characters except whitespaces

`[\D\S]` = [union (set theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29) of the above character groups = all characters.

Why? Because `\D` contains `\s` and `\S` contains `\d`.

If you want to match characters which are not dights nor whitespaces you can use `[^\d\s]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is invalidating itself as it goes.  Putting the regex inside of `[]` means it has to match one of the items inside of it.  These two items override each other, which end up matching everything.  In theory, anything that is non digit, would match every other char. available, and any non whitespace matches any digit and any other char. as well.

You can try using `[^\d\s]` which says to negate the match of any digit or any space.  Instead of having everything caught in the original regex, this negates the matching of both the `\d` and `\s`.  You can see testing done with it [here](http://rubular.com/r/GsaHRoflHr).